# Android how to copy folder with files on it from Internal memory to External

Tags: android, file-io

I need to find a way how to create files from specific folder in Internal Storage of my device to a specific folder in External Storage.

Example :

- I have 50 image files in `data/data/app_package/files/documents/server/userId/storage/` in Internal Storage.
- I want to copy all of the files in that directory to `/sdcard/Documents/Server/UserId/Storage/`

And the idea is that in some cases maybe I'll have to move files like 50MB and maybe more. Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
private void copyToFolder(String path) throws IOException {
    File selectedImage = new File(path);
    if (selectedImage.exists()) {
        String wall = selectedImage.getName();

        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
        out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/wallpapers/" + wall);
        copyFile( in , out); in .close(); in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does not exist");
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in , OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in .read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);

    }
}
```